# How to get text with Xpath while the text is not in clean structure

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to crawl the Extended Plot part of this webpage: https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/The_White_Asparagus_Triangulation

I tried this Xpath:

```
//span[contains(@id,'Extended')]/..//following-sibling::P
```

But I am missing this paragraph:

> That night Sheldon wakes up ...

Comment: I doubt in para tag naming i think `P` should be `p` like `//span[contains(@id,'Extended')]/..//following-sibling::p`.

Comment: It's because the text "That night Sheldon wakes up ..." isn't within a <p> on the website

Answer (score 0):

You have to include all `p` tags as well as `text` nodes following the `H2` your expression matches. Something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//span[contains(@id,'Extended')]/../following-sibling::p|//span[contains(@id,'Extended')]/../following-sibling::text()"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but then we will lose the order of the sentences in two commands.

Comment: No, I've tried with XALAN XSLT Processor and the order of the outputed text is the same as in the input. Have you tried?